# Logging in Magento 2.4+

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, log, debugging

What are the different way a developer can log messages in Magento 2.4+? Zend logger can't be used anymore either.

Comment: https://techurbane.com/how-to-add-custom-logs-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This will work with the newest Magento 2.4.3+:

```
    $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
    $logger = new \Zend_Log();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
```

This is just an example, but you have to adjust it this way.

Comment: worked for me too, easy and best way

Answer (score 11):

There are many ways to log messages currently and they are described below. Please do add on to this as a knowledge base.

- Log to the existing Magento log files in `var/log/`

This is done using `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` and is described in detail at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/log/log-magento.html. This is the quickest, and also follows Magento best practices.

- Log to a custom log file (not so quick)

This is done by extending `Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base` and is described in detail at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/log/custom-logger-handler.html. This can be followed in scenarios where you have a custom log file for a specific category of logs, maybe logs for a particular API integration. This is relatively longer to implement, and follows Magento best practices.

- Log to any log file (quick throwaway of sorts)

This is done using `Laminas\Log\Logger` and can be used for quick debugging using logs without involving the constructor DI and running `setup:di:compile` every time. This is not a good way, as it bypasses the constructor DI for instantiating classes.

```
$writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);

// $logger has log methods for different priorities like warning, notice, error, etc.
$logger->info('Hello World!');
$logger->notice('Hello World!');
$logger->warn('Hello World!');
```

- Of course, [xDebug](https://xdebug.org/). Please use xDebug for debugging purposes without writing debug log statements all over the codebase.

**Update (Sep 22, 2021):** To use the `Laminas_Log` module in Magento 2.4.3, please run `composer require laminas/laminas-log` as Magento 2.4.3 removes this module. Credit to @Derek Lee.

Answer (score 8):

After the release of the Magento 2.4.3 version, the Laminas-log module is removed. Thus, the previous method by using

```
    $writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . $path);
    $logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
```

is not work now.

To solve this problem, there is a temp fix by install the Laminas Log module again by using the composer:

Add the following code in composer.json's require

```
    "require": {
    ...
    "laminas/laminas-log": "*",
    ...
    },
```

This will make the Magento 2.4.3 support for the laminas Log.

Comment: to me dosn't make sense to add a new laminas-log dependency I think it is a better solution to create the log class https://www.pixiemedia.co.uk/blog/magento-zend-support-ending.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use several formats.

**Default logger**

1: In Magento default format

```
protected $_logger;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ...
) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;
}

public function logExample() {

    //To print string Output in debug.log
    $this->_logger->addDebug('Your Text Or Variables'); 
    
    // To print array Output in system.log
    $this->_logger->log('600', print_r($yourArray, true));

}
```

**Custom logger**

2: This will work with the older version of Magento 2.4.3:

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');
$logger->info(print_r($array, true)); //to log the array
```

3: This will work with the newest Magento 2.4.3+. it is tested on Magento 2.4.4, 2.4.6 version.

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');
$logger->info(print_r($array, true)); //to log the array
```

Comment: For 2.4.3+ incase of array how should I print it?

Comment: @AveshNaik, Thank you. I have added the array printing option in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way to debug:

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
   ->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug('Your Message');
```

Some other ways:

From M2.3.5, use this Laminas log library's snippet:

```
$writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');
```

Before M2.3.5, use this Zend log library's snippet:

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');
```

**Tips for PHPStorm**: Create a snippet shortcut to make this faster by adding new Live Templates on PHPStorm:

*Go to Files -> Prefences -> Editor -> Live Templates -> Add new:*

- Abbreviation: log
- Template text: the above log snippet
- Place `$END$` to your desired cursor position

Then type `log` and press the tab key, IDE will auto append the above snippet

Comment: Informative summary of answers

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
    } catch (\Zend_Log_Exception $e) {
        // throw exception
    }
    $logger = new \Zend_Log();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info('Event Called!');
```

Answer (score -3):

You can simply put this code where you are debugging

```
   $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
   $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
   $logger->addWriter($writer);
   $logger->info('Custom text message');
```

Here in info() put your query or variable or whatever and hit the file. After that you will see the custom.log file in your Magento root folder **var -> log -> custom.log**

Comment: Thanks, @Haider141. But I believe Zend_Log is no more available in Magento 2.4 and above. Hence my post to use Laminas_Log in the third point.

Comment: You're right, @Haider141. Zend_Log does in fact work, but is not maintained anymore https://framework.zend.com/ and Magento has a local copy of the deprecated Zend framework with magento/zendframework1 for compatibility. This is why it works, but no Zend file should be used as a best practice, in my opinion. I have no assumed anything either. Deprecated/abandoned code shouldn't be used unless there is no alternative, hence my post.